# `stack` and the file path limit on Windows

Tags: ghc, haskell-stack

Eventually I hit the file path limit while using [simplelocalnet](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/distributed-process-simplelocalnet-0.2.3.2/docs/Control-Distributed-Process-Backend-SimpleLocalnet.html).

In https://www.fpcomplete.com/blog/2015/08/stack-ghc-windows Michael Snoyman explains a (rather obvious) workaround as last point: Move my code under a shorter path.

Is there any functionality implemented in `stack`/`ghc` yet that fixes that bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack has been shortening some internal file paths on Windows for a few versions now by using an 8 character hash. AFAIK no other measures to alleviate the issue are planned.

So, to use stack on Windows it's still a good idea to set `STACK_ROOT` to `c:\stack` or an even shorter path.

Regarding GHC, I'm not sure what they should do about it or how it's even their problem, but I wouldn't know either.

Comment: Snoyman noted in the above link that GHC must make use of the `\\?\` prefix for supporting longer paths on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase Window's NTFS path size limit to roughly 32,000 characters by modifying your registry and enabling long path names:

> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem]
>   "LongPathsEnabled"=dword:00000001